# How to group all recorders that start with a number together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a simple rails blog that displays the list of all artist and I would like to group all those that start with a number in a group called **0-9**, followed by **a, b, c, d** where **a, b, c, d** displays artists that start with those respective characters.

Currently I can group the characters but I have no idea how to merge the numbers to a single group. What I have is **0, 1, 2...9** where **0..9** are single groups of the array.

My controller code is below

```
@artists = Artist.order(name: :asc).group_by{|u| u.name[0].upcase}
```

and my sorting code is

```
<% @artists.each do |letter, artists| -%>
  <h4><%= letter %></h4>
  <ul>
    <% artists.first(4).each do |artist| -%>
      <li><%= render artist %></li>
    <% end -%>
  </ul>              
<% end %>
```

This gives me the result I have here http://netpod.site.com.ng/artists
of which everything is fine. But I want to group those with numbers as one array set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the problem 100% correctly but I think you're looking for something like:

```
["12-d", "50 cent", "ACDC", "Mr Cool"].group_by{ |artist| ((artist =~ /[0-9]/) ? "numbers" : artist[0]) }
```

which would return:

```
{"numbers"=>["12-d", "50 cent"], "A"=>["ACDC"], "M"=>["Mr Cool"]}
```

Comment: perfect.  `@artists = Artist.order(name: :asc).group_by{ |artist| ((artist.name =~ /[0-9]/) ? "0-9" : artist.name[0]) }` Thanks